# selenium IDE add-on not adding to the Firefox 55.0.1 browser in windows 10

Tags: selenium, ide

I have installed Firefox 55.0.1 browser in windows 10 , when I tried to add selenium IDE add-on to the browser it was installing & asking restart, but it was not showing in the tools though it was showing in available add-ons.

Please guide me.

Comment: Selenium IDE is no longer supported, why are you trying it with latest firefox?

Comment: @TarunLalwani Selenium IDE is, easy to create scripts, later you can modify.

Answer (score 1):

Open Firefox Menu.

[image]

Click on **Customize**

[image]

You'll see the Selenium IDE button in the left panel. Simply drag and drop it to the menu on the right side and you are done.